# Primefaces commandButton doesn't execute action on the Bean

Tags: spring-boot, primefaces

I'm using SpringBoot 2.7.5 with Primefaces 12.0.0

I'm having some trouble with uploading a file to the server because if I put `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, and I click on the button, the function specified on `action` attribute isn't called at all

The .xhtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <ui:define name="component">

        <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:fileUpload value="#{uploadFilesController.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" action="#{uploadFilesController.parseFile}" skinSimple="true"/>
        </h:form>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

The Bean

```java
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class UploadFilesController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UploadedFile file;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        System.out.println("getFile");
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
        System.out.println("SET!");
    }
    
    public void parseFile() {

        System.out.println(file.getFileName());

        if (file != null) {
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Successful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

    }

}
```

When I click the button, after selecting some file the page updates but nothing happens on the backend.

If I remove the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, I get an error about the file is null.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can try my following example in order to create an automatic fileUpload.

web.xml (not sure if necessary)

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-lass>
    </filter>
```

.xhtml

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:fileUpload id="uploadFile" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"
                                  value="#{backing.file}" label="Select new file"
                                  auto="true" listener="#{backing.handleFileUpload}"/>
</h:form>
```

backing.java

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    UploadedFile newfile = event.getFile();
    //do some checks on newly added file
}
```